# How to contact a non-standard API using Angular ngResource

Tags: angularjs, ibm-cloud

The API I am using requires a non-standard where clause if I try to search for a particular non-id field.  The endpoint I need is:

http://127.0.0.1:4001/api/testusers/findOne?userName=Anton

So this will find me the first record in the testusers table whose column (userName) = 'Anton'.

My standard service is:

```js
angular.
  module('shared.testUser').
  factory('TestUser', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
      return $resource('http://127.0.0.1:4001/api/testusers/:id', {id:'@id'},//parameters
            {
                update: {
                      method: 'PUT' // To send the HTTP Put request when calling this custom update method.
                }
                 
            });
    }
  ]);
```

and my calling function is:

```js
    self.checkUsersEntryDirection = function(){ //NOT WORKING
      self.testuser = TestUser.get({ username: 'anton' }, function() {
        console.log(angular.toJson(self.testuser));
      }); // get() returns a single entry
    }
```

Clearly this doesn't work and I can't use the standard get approach. Can anyone think how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a secondary factory `TestUserByName`, and make the following changes:

```
angular.
  module('shared.testUser').
  factory('TestUserByName', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
      return $resource('http://127.0.0.1:4001/api/testusers/findOne?userName:username', null,
            {
                update: {
                      method: 'PUT' // To send the HTTP Put request when calling this custom update method.
                }

            });
    }
  ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the `get` action method with two parameters:

```
var params = {id: "findOne", username: "anton"};

self.checkUsersEntryDirection = function(){
  self.testuser = TestUser.get(params, function() {
    console.log(angular.toJson(self.testuser));
  }); // get() returns a single entry
}
```

The `id` parameter will override the default and `username` parameter will be added as a query string.

From the DOCS:

> Each key value in the parameter object is first bound to url template if present and then any excess keys are appended to the url search query after the ?.
>
> Given a template `/path/:verb` and parameter `{verb:'greet', salutation:'Hello'}` results in URL `/path/greet?salutation=Hello`.

--[AngularJS ngResource $resource Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)